# How to copy part of dynamic tables in excel based on an id?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I have 2 dynamics tables in a worksheet

```
    projectId | start    | end      | employee | name | amount
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    5013-001  | 12-01-01 | 13-01-01 |  001     | bob  | 100 $
                                    |  021     | foo  | 200 $
                                    |  101     | bar  | 300 $
                                    |  111     | luc  | 300 $
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    total 5013-001                                      900 $
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    5013-002  | 12-01-01 | 13-01-01 |  001     | bob  | 150 $
                                    |  021     | foo  | 205 $
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    total 5013-002                                      355 $

    --Snip--
```

```
    projectId | expenseCode     | total
    ---------------------------------------
    5013-001   | T01 Summary      | 4504$
               | D01 Summary      |  204$
    total 5013-001                | 4708$
    ---------------------------------------
    5013-002   | T01 Summary      | 1007$
    total 5013-002                | 1007$

    --Snip--
```

expected result :

```
    projectId | start    | end      | employee | name | amount
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    5013-001  | 12-01-01 | 13-01-01 |  001     | bob  | 100 $
                                    |  021     | foo  | 200 $
                                    |  101     | bar  | 300 $
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    total 5013-001                                      600 $
    ----------------------------------------------------------

    projectId | expenseCode     | total
    ---------------------------------------
    5013-001   | T01 Summary      | 4504$
               | D01 Summary      |  204$
    total 5013-001                | 4708$
    ---------------------------------------

    --page break--
```

How would you proceed to have both tables filtered by projectId, each on one page? (number of columns is fix, but not rows!)

I'm guessing a macro but I though there might something simpler.

If I should indeed use a macro, is the engine powerful enough? I never coded excel macro, so I'll gladly take any tips/references.

One last *subjective* question : Do you think this problem is solvable in ~1 workday?

Comment: can you post a link to a dummy sample set of data?

Comment: Do the same projectIds appear in both tables in the same sequence? If not, are the projectIds in ascending sequence so the correct action can be determined if one is missing? This should not take long to program (much less than 8 hours) or run with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Your profile says you program so I assume the problem is that you do not know VBA syntax.  I have made assumption about your tables but I also assume you can amend my code if my assumptions are incorrect.

I have created a copy of your data in worksheet TblSrc.

Table 1:

[image: Source table 1]

Table 2:

[image: Source table 2]

I duplicated these rows so I have eight sub tables in each main table.  The code relies on there being a one-to-one match between the two main tables.  I do not check the two sub tables match.  This is not enough data for any real timings but for, what it is worth, the macro below took .03 seconds to copy four pairs of sub tables to create:

[image: Destination table]

I created the lines of hyphens by merging the cells, setting the first to '- and setting the horizontal alignment to Fill.  I identify separator rows by checking for the first character of a column A being hyphen.  The single quote before the hyphen is to stop it looking like an invalid negative number.  It is not part of the cell value.

This macro is not the fastest approach to this problem but will copy any formatting in your sub tables from source to destination.

There are some comments within the macro but perhaps not enough.  I suggest you step through the macro with F5 (run until next breakpoint) and F8 (execute next statement).

Come back with questions and I will my improve answer.  If you can give more information about your data, I may be able to show you other approaches.

Warning it is 21:45 here and I am not sure about my internet access tomorrow.  I will respond to questions as soon as I can.

Option Explicit
   Sub CombineTables()

```
 Dim CellValue() As Variant
 Dim ColCrnt As Long
 Dim ColMax As Long
 Dim Found As Boolean
 Dim RngStgHeader1 As String
 Dim RngStgHeader2 As String
 Dim RngStgHeaderX As String
 Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
 Dim RowSrcSubTab1End As Long
 Dim RowSrcSubTab1Start As Long
 Dim RowSrcSubTab2End As Long
 Dim RowSrcSubTab2Start As Long
 Dim RowSrcTab1Crnt As Long
 Dim RowSrcTab2Crnt As Long
 Dim RowSrcTab1End As Long
 Dim RowSrcTab1Start As Long
 Dim RowSrcTab2End As Long
 Dim RowSrcTab2Start As Long
 Dim timeStart As Double

  Application.EnableEvents = False   ' Prevents any event routine being called
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Screen updating causes flicker and is slow

  timeStart = Timer     ' Seconds since midnight

 ' Gather information from source worksheet
 With Worksheets("TblSrc")

   ' These statements find the last row and the last column containing a value
   RowSrcTab2End = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , _
                                                       xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
   ColMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , _
                                                 xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

   CellValue = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowSrcTab2End, ColMax)).Value
   ' CellValue is now a 2D array containing every value from the used range.
   ' The first dimension will be for the rows and the second for the columns.
   ' The lower bound of each dimension will be 1.  The upper bounds will be
   ' RowSrcTab2End and ColMax.  Having the rows as the first dimension is
   ' unusual is the nature of arrays loaded from or to a worksheet.

   ' I did not have to copy the data to an array.  I could have done so
   ' because I believe searching for sub tables will be sufficiently faster
   ' to make this a sensible choice.

 End With

 ' Find the start of the main tables.
 For RowSrcTab1Crnt = 1 To RowSrcTab2End
   If CellValue(RowSrcTab1Crnt, 1) = "projectId" And _
      CellValue(RowSrcTab1Crnt, 2) = "start" Then
      RowSrcTab1Start = RowSrcTab1Crnt
      Exit For
   End If
 Next

 For RowSrcTab2Crnt = RowSrcTab1Crnt + 1 To RowSrcTab2End
   If CellValue(RowSrcTab2Crnt, 1) = "projectId" And _
      CellValue(RowSrcTab2Crnt, 2) = "expenseCode" Then
      RowSrcTab2Start = RowSrcTab2Crnt
      Exit For
   End If
 Next

 RowSrcTab1End = RowSrcTab2Start - 1

 ' Output values found to the Immediate window as a check
 Debug.Print "Table 1 rows: " & RowSrcTab1Start & " - " & RowSrcTab1End
 Debug.Print "Table 2 rows: " & RowSrcTab2Start & " - " & RowSrcTab2End

 With Worksheets("TblDest")
   ' Clear current contents of destination sheet
   .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
 End With

 ' Build range strings for table headers because
 ' they are needed for every projectId
 RngStgHeader1 = "A" & RowSrcTab1Start & ":" & _
                                 ColNumToCode(ColMax) & RowSrcTab1Start
 RngStgHeader2 = "A" & RowSrcTab2Start & ":" & _
                                 ColNumToCode(ColMax) & RowSrcTab2Start

 RowSrcTab1Crnt = RowSrcTab1Start + 1  ' \ Start point for search
 RowSrcTab2Crnt = RowSrcTab2Start + 1  ' / for first sub tables
 RowDestCrnt = 1  ' Position for first output sub tables

 Do While True

   ' Search for start of next sub table 1
   Found = False
   Do While RowSrcTab1Crnt < RowSrcTab2Start
     If CellValue(RowSrcTab1Crnt, 1) <> "" And _
        Left(CellValue(RowSrcTab1Crnt, 1), 1) <> "-" Then
       ' Assume next table 1 row with column A not empty and not starting
       ' with a hyphen is the start of next table 1 sub table
       Found = True
       RowSrcSubTab1Start = RowSrcTab1Crnt
       RowSrcTab1Crnt = RowSrcTab1Crnt + 1  ' Prepare for search for end
       Exit Do
     End If
     RowSrcTab1Crnt = RowSrcTab1Crnt + 1
   Loop
   If Not Found Then
     ' No next sub table 1 found.  All done.
     Exit Do
   End If

   ' Search for end of this sub table 1
   Found = False
   Do While RowSrcTab1Crnt < RowSrcTab2Start
     If LCase(Left(CellValue(RowSrcTab1Crnt, 1), 5)) = "total" Then
       Found = True
       RowSrcSubTab1End = RowSrcTab1Crnt
       RowSrcTab1Crnt = RowSrcTab1Crnt + 1  ' Prepare for next loop
       Exit Do
     End If
     RowSrcTab1Crnt = RowSrcTab1Crnt + 1
   Loop
   If Not Found Then
     ' End of table not found.  Either data error or program error
     Debug.Assert False     ' Interpreter will stop here to allow
                            ' examination of variables
     Exit Do
   End If

   ' Search for start of next sub table 2
   Found = False
   Do While RowSrcTab2Crnt < RowSrcTab2End
     If CellValue(RowSrcTab2Crnt, 1) <> "" And _
        Left(CellValue(RowSrcTab2Crnt, 1), 1) <> "-" Then
       ' Assume next table 2 row with column A not empty and not starting
       ' with a hyphen is the start of next table 2 sub table
       Found = True
       RowSrcSubTab2Start = RowSrcTab2Crnt
       RowSrcTab2Crnt = RowSrcTab2Crnt + 1  ' Prepare for search for end
       Exit Do
     End If
     RowSrcTab2Crnt = RowSrcTab2Crnt + 1
   Loop
   If Not Found Then
     ' No next sub table 2 found.  Have table 1 so have data or program error.
     Debug.Assert False     ' Interpreter will stop here to allow
                            ' examination of variables
     Exit Do
   End If

   ' Search for end of this sub table 2
   Found = False
   Do While RowSrcTab2Crnt < RowSrcTab2End
     If LCase(Left(CellValue(RowSrcTab2Crnt, 1), 5)) = "total" Then
       Found = True
       RowSrcSubTab2End = RowSrcTab2Crnt
       RowSrcTab2Crnt = RowSrcTab2Crnt + 1  ' Prepare for next loop
       Exit Do
     End If
     RowSrcTab2Crnt = RowSrcTab2Crnt + 1
   Loop
   If Not Found Then
     ' End of table not found.  Either data error or program error
     Debug.Assert False     ' Interpreter will stop here to allow
                            ' examination of variables
     Exit Do
   End If

   ' Have start and end of next sub tables.

   ' Copy header row for table 1
   Worksheets("TblSrc").Range(RngStgHeader1).Copy _
                     Destination:=Worksheets("TblDest").Cells(RowDestCrnt, 1)
   RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
   ' Copy sub table 1 plus rows before and after which should be dividing rows
   RngStgHeaderX = "A" & RowSrcSubTab1Start - 1 & ":" & _
                                   ColNumToCode(ColMax) & RowSrcSubTab1End + 1
   Worksheets("TblSrc").Range(RngStgHeaderX).Copy _
                      Destination:=Worksheets("TblDest").Cells(RowDestCrnt, 1)
   RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + RowSrcSubTab1End - RowSrcSubTab1Start + 4
   ' Copy header row for table 2
   Worksheets("TblSrc").Range(RngStgHeader2).Copy _
                     Destination:=Worksheets("TblDest").Cells(RowDestCrnt, 1)
   RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
   ' Copy sub table 2 plus rows before and after which should be dividing rows
   RngStgHeaderX = "A" & RowSrcSubTab2Start - 1 & ":" & _
                                   ColNumToCode(ColMax) & RowSrcSubTab2End + 1
   Worksheets("TblSrc").Range(RngStgHeaderX).Copy _
                      Destination:=Worksheets("TblDest").Cells(RowDestCrnt, 1)
   RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + RowSrcSubTab2End - RowSrcSubTab2Start + 3

   ' Warning there is a limit of 1026 on the number of horizontal page breaks
   Worksheets("TblDest").HPageBreaks.Add _
                           Before:=Worksheets("TblDest").Cells(RowDestCrnt, 1)
 Loop

 Debug.Print Timer - timeStart

 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub

Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  ' Convert column number (such as 1, 2, 27, etc.) to
  ' column code (such as A, B, AA, etc.)

  Dim Code As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' Last updated 3 Feb 12.  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    Code = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      Code = Chr(65 + PartNum) & Code
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = Code

End Function
```

Comment: I should add that I can also amend the code if I have seriously misunderstood the nature of your tables.